# How can I store a series of computed cell values into consecutive Google Sheets cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell

I have a sheet that gets a lot of data from external sources (using GOOGLEFINANCE(), IMPORTJSON(), etc.) to compute a total value of a series of assets. What I'd like to do is preserve the value of the "total" cell every day so I can draw a chart of long-term behavior. I had a solution in place that would find the correct cell to write to and record the value, but
`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell_name).setValue(todays_total);` pukes with an exception: You can't write to another cell.

It occurs to me that I could have a function that does something like:

```
function do_the_thing(todays_total) {
  if (this_is_the_correct_cell_to_write_to) { // This is a solved problem
    return todays_total;
  } else {
    return PREVIOUS_VALUE_OF_THIS_CELL; // If cell previously had value, return it. Otherwise, leave empty
  }
}
```

I'd just copy-paste this function into a column of cells and they'd get about their business. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your problem is best solved by a direct script instead of using a custom function inside cell

Comment: I would just run this procedure (using the method you stated created google to puke) every hour and just have it set values if changes are needed.

Comment: You can only use read methods with custom functions (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services), so no `setValue`. Because of this, as others said, don't use a custom function, and use a regular script instead. Is there a reason you cannot do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
function storevals(a,b) {
  let vp = a + b;
  let vm = a - b;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange(1,1,1,2).setValues([[vp,vm]]);//saves them in A1,B1
  sh.getRange(1,1,2,1).setValues([[vp],[vm]]);//saves them in A1,A2
}
```